# Query segmentation with spell check

Tags: python, string, search, spell-checking

Assuming I have a fixed list of multi word names like:
`Water`
`Tocopherol (Vitamin E)`
`Vitamin D`
`PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil`

I want the following input/output results:

1. `Water, PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil` -> `Water`, `PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil`
2. `PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil` -> `PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil`
3. `wter PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil` -> `Water`, `PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil`
4. `Vitamin E` -> `Tocopherol (Vitamin E)`

I need it to be performant and the ability to recognize that either there are too many close matches and no close matches. With 1 its relatively easy because I can separate by the comma. Most times the input list is separated by the comma so this works 80% of the time but even this has the small issue. Take for example 4. Once separated, 4's ideal match is not returned by most spellcheck libraries (I've tried a number) because the edit distance to `Vitamin D` is much smaller. There are some websites that do this well but I'm lost as to how to do it.

The second part to this problem is, how do I do word segmentation on top. Let's say a given list doesn't have a comma, I need to be able to recognize that. Simplest example being `Water Vtamin D` should become `Water`, `Vitamin D`. I can give a ton of examples but I think this gives a good idea of the problem.

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/QXabQXWP) a list of names that can be used.

Comment: Given the subject matter do you have a moderately long list of words/phrases that you are dealing with?

Comment: Yea I have a list of about 5000 names

Comment: Do you have like the code and and example for us to use?

Comment: I don't have any code - I was playing around with this earlier using spellcheck libraries available on python (tried a number of them). I'm looking more for for of an approach/algorithm/idea on how this can be solved. Because standard spellcheck relies heavily on edit distance, I need something else, and I don't know what options are out there.

Comment: For a working example see https://www.skincarisma.com/ingredient-analyzer. All my examples work there except the one without the comma. Here's one that solves the one without the comma: https://incidecoder.com/decode-inci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer builds upon @Rafaels answer.

1. `process.extractOne` in FuzzyWuzzy uses the scorer `fuzz.WRatio` by default. This is a combination of multiple scorers provided by FuzzyWuzzy, that works well for the dataset Seatgeek is working with. So you might want to try around with other scorers to see which one performs best for you. However note, that quite a few of your elements might be hard to distinguish using the edit distance. E.g. `Vitamin E` <-> `Vitamin D` only need a single edit, even though they are something completely different. The same behavior also occurs with glycereth-7
2. FuzzyWuzzy is relatively slow, so when your working with a bigger dataset you might want to use [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) instead (I am the author) which provides similar algorithms, but has a better performance.
3. `process.extractOne` preprocesses the input strings by default (lowercases and replaces non alphanumeric characters with whitespaces). Since your probably searching for elements multiple times it would make sense to preprocess the possible choices once ahead of time and deactivate this behavior to safe some time:

```py
process.extractOne(str2Match,strOptions, processor=None)
```

### Differences between RapidFuzz and FuzzyWuzzy

Since you reported differences in the results between RapidFuzz and FuzzyWuzzy here are some possible reasons:

1. I do not round results. So you wil get a floating point like 42.22 instead of 42 as a result
2. In case your not using the fast FuzzyWuzzy implementation, that uses python-Levenshtein you might get different results, since it uses difflib which is a different metric. It produces very similar results most of the time but not always
3. In case your using the fast implementation any partial ratio like partial_ratio, WRatio ... might return wrong results in FuzzyWuzzy since partial_ratio is broken (see [here](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/79))
4. Passing processor=None to extract/extractOne has a different meaning in RapidFuzz and FuzzyWuzzy. In RapidFuzz it will deactivate preprocessing, while in FuzzyWuzzy it will still use the default of the score. As an example for

```
extract(..., scorer=fuzz.WRatio, processor=None)
```

FuzzyWuzzy will still preprocess the strings inside WRatio, so there is no way to deactivate preprocessing. I personally think this is a bad design, so I changed it to give the user the possibility to deactivate the processor, which is likely what you want to achieve when passing `processor=None`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to fix the `Vitamin E` issue using an algorithm (see my answer). I did notice that fuzzyfuzzy is relatively slow. Thanks for the two tips. Do you have any pointers as to how I can go about try to separate out words like `wter PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil`. The posted algorithm works for only one extraction.

Comment: Also, when I added `, processor=None`, it works fine on fuzzywuzzy but not yours. I preprocessed by only lower casing it, since symbols are somewhat important here. Without `, processor=None`, I get 0.0420 sec per lookup on fuzzywuzzy and 0.0036 on yours, which is crazy. Thank you so much!

Comment: I added differences between RapidFuzz and FuzzyWuzzy to my answer. Some are things I changed, because I did not find them very user friendly and some are bugs in FuzzyWuzzy (Should probably add this as a section to my documentation). Other things might very well be bugs on my side ;)

Comment: Thank you for the update. As for segmentation on top of this, do you have any pointers as to how I can go about it? I feel like correction makes segmentation significantly harder.

Answer (score 2):

### Context

This is a case of [approximate string matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) or [fuzzy matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_matching_(computer-assisted_translation)). There is good materials and libraries about that.

There are different libraries and ways to cover this. I will restrict to relatively simple libraries

Some cool libraries:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import pandas as pd
import string
```

### First Part

Let's place the data to play around. I try to reproduce the above example, hope it is fine.

```
# Set up dataframe
d = {'originals': [["Water","PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil"],
                   ["PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil"],
                   ["wter"," PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil"],
                   ['Vitamin E']],
     'correct': [["Water","PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil"],
                 ["PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil"],
                 ['Water', 'PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil'],
                 ['Tocopherol (Vitamin E)']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
                                 originals                                  correct
0  [Water, PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil]  [Water, PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil]
1            [PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil]         [PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil]
2     [wter,  PEG-60 Hydrnated Castor Oil]  [Water, PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil]
3                              [Vitamin E]                 [Tocopherol (Vitamin E)]
```

From the above we have the statement of the problem: we have some original wording and want to change it.

Which are the correct options for us:

```
strOptions = ['Water', "Tocopherol (Vitamin E)",
             "Vitamin D", "PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil"]
```

This functions are going to help us. I try to document them well.

```
def function_proximity(str2Match,strOptions):
    """
    This function help to get the first guess by similiarity.

    paramters
    ---------
    str2Match: string. The string to match.
    strOptions: list of strings. Those are the possibilities to match.
    """
    highest = process.extractOne(str2Match,strOptions)
    return highest[0]
def check_strings(x, strOptions):
    """
    Takes a list of string and give you a list of string best matched.
    :param x: list of string to link / matched
    :param strOptions:
    :return: list of string matched
    """
    list_results = []
    for i in x:
        i=str(i)
        list_results.append(function_proximity(i,strOptions))
    return list_results
```

Let's apply to the dataframe:

```
df['solutions_1'] = df['originals'].apply(lambda x: check_strings(x, strOptions))
```

Let's check the results, by comparing the columns.

```
print(df['solutions_1'] == df['correct'])
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
dtype: bool
```

As you can see the solution work in the four cases.

### Second Part

**Problem** example solution:
You have `Water Vtamin D` should become `Water, Vitamin D`.

Let's create a list of valid words.

```
list_words = []
for i in strOptions:
    print(i.split(' '))
    list_words = list_words + i.split(' ')
# Lower case and remove punctionation
list_valid_words = []
for i in list_words:
    i = i.lower()
    list_valid_words.append(i.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))
print(list_valid_words)
['water', 'tocopherol', 'vitamin', 'e', 'vitamin', 'd', 'peg60', 'hydrogenated', 'castor', 'oil']
```

That if the list of words that are valid.

```
def remove_puntuation_split(x):
    """
    This function remove puntuation and split the string into tokens.
    :param x: string
    :return: list of proper tokens
    """
    x = x.lower()
    # Remove all puntuation
    x = x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return x.split(' ')

tokens = remove_puntuation_split(x)
# Clean tokens
clean_tokens = [function_proximity(x,list_valid_words) for x in tokens]
# Matched tokens with proper selection
tokens_clasified = [function_proximity(x,strOptions) for x in tokens]
# Removed repeated
tokens_clasified =  list(set(tokens_clasified))
print(tokens_clasified)
['Vitamin D', 'Water']
```

That is as required initially.
However those could fail a bit, particularly when Vitamin E and D are combined.

## References

- https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python
- https://pbpython.com/record-linking.html
- https://pbpython.com/record-linking.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but unfortunately it breaks down rather quickly with a large dataset. Here's a list of ingredients https://pastebin.com/QXabQXWP. With that list the output is "['tocopheryl acetate (vitamin e)', 'ceramide', 'water']".

Comment: What do you mean breaks? in terms of time? a wrong answer?

Comment: Yea. Given the input "Water Vtamin D" the answers are somewhat unrelated. (['tocopheryl acetate (vitamin e)', 'ceramide', 'water'])

Comment: There were two parts, one separated by commas and another not separated by comma, what above I called "Second Part". In that part that particular case is considered, providing results ['Vitamin D', 'Water'].

Comment: Did you try it with the entire list? With the entire list I get `(['tocopheryl acetate (vitamin e)', 'ceramide', 'water'])`. Also it seems like you are using a set which basically hides a symptom of problem. Ideally we should not be getting any repeats unless there is a repeat of the ingredient itself in a misspelled way. This becomes clear when you start using the full list.

Comment: I used the cases mentioned in the original question. To use a longer list could be ok, but it possible that other consideration need to be included, such as parallelization of the process or use spark instead of python.

Comment: Yea, I should have posted the list from the beginning but have now included it in the question. With a very small list your algorithm works, but once it gets slightly larger (>100) it doesn't produce the desired result. Parallelization doesn't really help with anything here since speed is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I expanded on the other answers to make it work on the provided list. It's sort of an algorithm using `fuzzywuzzy` and seems to work for a case like `vitamin e`.

```
def merge_scores(text, matches, match_func):
    new_scores = []
    for match in matches:
        new_scores.append((match[0], (match[1] + match_func(match[0], text)) / 2))
    return sorted(new_scores, key=lambda m:m[1], reverse=True)

def get_best_match(text):
    fuzz_matches = process.extractBests(text, INGREDIENTS, limit=10, scorer=fuzz.ratio)
    if fuzz_matches[0][1] < 80 or fuzz_matches[0][1] == fuzz_matches[1][1]:
        fuzz_matches = process.extractBests(text, INGREDIENTS, limit=10, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
        # Combine only if the top 5 aren't perfect matches
        if fuzz_matches[4][1] != 100:
            fuzz_matches = merge_scores(text, fuzz_matches, fuzz.ratio)
    if fuzz_matches[0][1] == fuzz_matches[1][1]:
        fuzz_matches = process.extractBests(text, INGREDIENTS, limit=10, scorer=fuzz.WRatio)
    if fuzz_matches[0][1] == fuzz_matches[1][1]:
        return '', 0
    return fuzz_matches[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy and paste the list from https://pastebin.com/QXabQXWP in file list_terms_v3.txt.

```
"""

References
https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python

Questions Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844582/query-segmentation-with-spell-check

"""

from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd
import string

#strOptions = ['Water', "Tocopherol (Vitamin E)",
#             "Vitamin D", "PEG-60 Hydrogenated Castor Oil"]
strOptions = pd.read_csv("list_terms_v3.txt", sep='\n', header=None)
strOptions = strOptions[0].tolist()
print(strOptions.__len__())

"""
Create a list of key workds
"""
list_words = []
for i in strOptions:
    print(i.split(' '))
    list_words = list_words + i.split(' ')
# Lower case and remove punctionation
list_valid_words = []
for i in list_words:
    i = i.lower()
    list_valid_words.append(i.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))


def function_proximity(str2Match,strOptions = strOptions):
    """
    This function help to get the first guess by similiarity.

    paramters
    ---------
    str2Match: string. The string to match.
    strOptions: list of strings. Those are the possibilities to match.
    """
    highest = process.extractOne(str2Match,strOptions)
    return highest[0]
def check_strings(x, strOptions):
    """
    Takes a list of string and give you a list of string best matched.
    :param x: list of string to link / matched
    :param strOptions:
    :return: list of string matched
    """
    list_results = []
    for i in x:
        i=str(i)
        list_results.append(function_proximity(i))
    return list_results

"""
2 Option
"""


def remove_puntuation_split(x):
    """
    This function remove puntuation and split the string into tokens.
    :param x: string
    :return: list of proper tokens
    """
    x = x.lower()
    # Remove all puntuation
    x = x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return x.split(' ')

def clean_tokens_funct(x, strOptions=strOptions):
    if x in strOptions:
        return x
    else:
        return function_proximity(x,strOptions=strOptions)


def searcher(x):
    tokens = remove_puntuation_split(x)
    clean_tokens = [clean_tokens_funct(x, strOptions=list_valid_words) for x in tokens]
    # Matched tokens with proper selection
    tokens_clasified = [function_proximity(x,strOptions=strOptions) for x in tokens]
    # Removed repeated
    tokens_clasified =  list(set(tokens_clasified))
    return tokens_clasified
```

Up to here everything fine, to check:

```
x = "Water Vtamin E"
print(searcher(x))
['Tocopheryl Acetate (Vitamin E)', 'Water']
```

However previous could file in some cases. The problem is that Vitamin D does not appear in the list, but if added everything should be fine.

```
x = "Water Vtamin D"
print(searcher(x))
['Tocopheryl Acetate (Vitamin E)', 'Ceramide', 'Water']
```

Or another case for problem:

```
x = "Water  D"
print(searcher(x))
['Ceramide', 'Water']
```

In case you just want to compare with the list you have then use  `function_proximity`

```
x = 'Actinidia Chinensis Fruit'
print(function_proximity(x))
Luffa Cylindrica Fruit/Leaf/Stem Extract


x = 'Nelumbo Nucifera Callus Culture'
print(function_proximity(x))
Nelumbo Nucifera Callus Culture Extract
```

Comment: Also when you give it things like `Actinidia Chinensis Fruit` it just repeats itself. Or even `Nelumbo Nucifera Callus Culture`, using your solution, gives two incorrect results `['Nelumbo Nucifera Germ Extract\n', 'Leontopodium Alpinum Callus Culture Extract\n']` when infact it's just missing one word `extract`. The solution I posted above covers all these cases including the ones you posted (mine automatically ignores the vitamin D instead of trying to find something for it)

Comment: As an aside note, you don't need to mess around with pandas just to read a simple line by line file. For your code, you could have just done this and avoided 2 separate loops and much cleaner code:
`
for line in open('ingredients_list.txt').readlines():
    strOptions.append(line)
    list_words = list_words + line.split(' ')`